# How to include commas in an input while not interfering with a calculation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added commas to an input to make the number easier to read. I then have a function that displays a new value based on that input. It works -- until the value is longer than four digits (X,XXX). At that point it returns NaN. Anyone know what's going wrong?

**HTML**

```
<input class="number" id="loan_amount" oninput="calculate()">
<input id="savings_number">
```

**Function to calculate savings**

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('loan_amount').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('savings_number'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * 0.01;
    result.value = myResult;        
}
```

**Function to add commas and remove all characters except numbers**

```
$('input.number').keyup(function (event) {
  // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }

  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  var testDecimal = testDecimals(currentVal);
  if (testDecimal.length > 1) {
    console.log("You cannot enter more than one decimal point");
    currentVal = currentVal.slice(0, -1);
  }
  $(this).val(replaceCommas(currentVal));

});

function testDecimals(currentVal) {
  var count;
  currentVal.match(/\./g) === null ? count = 0 : count = currentVal.match(/\./g);
  return count;
}

function replaceCommas(yourNumber) {
  var components = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
  if (components.length === 1) 
    components[0] = yourNumber;
  components[0] = components[0].replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  if (components.length === 2)
    components[1] = components[1].replace(/\D/g, "");
  return components.join(".");
}
```

Comment: `myBox1` is a *string*. Assuming it could have commas, you could try `var myResult = +(myBox1.replace(/,/g, "")) * 0.01;` instead.

Comment: @Santi No need to use the unary `+` to convert to a number, the multiplication `*` will do that implicitly (JS can only multiply numbers :D).

Comment: Input.number will bite you on the ass. It behaves differently then a regular input be prepared to smash your head against the wall when you come across them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `oninput` event runs before Jquery's `onkeyup` event.  This means that your calculations occur before the commas have been removed - resulting in NaN.

Is there some reason why the calculate function can't be included at the end of the `keyup` event handler?  That way, you can be sure that it will always run after you have removed the commas.